# Wrapping multiple Lists in IDictionary

Tags: c#, list, .net-4.0, idictionary

I have a class ObjectBatch as follows:

```
[Serializable]    
class ObjectBatch : IDictionary<string, IObjModel>
    {
        List<Tuple<string, IObjModel>> ModelATypes;
        List<Tuple<string, IObjModel>> ModelBTypes;
        List<Tuple<string, IObjModel>> ModelCTypes;

        /* IDictionary implementations follow */
    }
```

This class is solely responsible for adding/removing, modifying lists based on a property of IObjModel. **Is this a bad design?** It **feels** fine to me; however, since I haven't seen an implementation like this before, I was just wondering if this is bad, and if so, why?

**Edit**
Assume a unique string is enforced (but at a higher level) and that IObjModels are of a composite nature (composed at a higher level). Also, note the addition of the Serializable attribute - I forgot this initially.

This class basically saves the elements of the individual collections. This class is not accessible by a user. It is an internal storage object.

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what's going on, but... if you need `IDictionary<K,V>` semantics then why don't you use a bunch of `Dictionary<string, IObjModel>` objects internally too, rather than `List<Tuple<string, IObjModel>>`?

Comment: as a separate node, you should avoid Hungarian notation on your type names, consider using `IObjectModel` as the name for your type.

Comment: @LukeH: tried to explain a bit more detail without getting into the higher level details and objects that push/pull data and compose IObjModels from ObjectBatch.

Comment: @Keivan: I would edit and change names to Foo, Bar, Fizz, and Buzz if you like ... ;) These are simplified names only intended to provide the necessary data types and convey their intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fine as object composition, but you should not inherit this from Dictionary. What is the purpose of it? If you want user to search on this object using key, it will be return from which of 3 lists? If key or object is self descriptive to type of record, why storing them in different list?

```
ObjectBatch[key] <-- get from A or B or C?
Add(IobjectModel) <-- will add to which list?
```

Comment: I handle these methods by testing the base type of IObjModel, instance a KeyValuePair if necessary ...but all of the functions of the IDictionary work without exposing any of the internal implementation of 'how' it knows which collection to add, remove, or modify.

Comment: I went ahead and refactored with a single `List<Tuple<T1, T2>>`. Thanks for the advice.